# Using Apex-Chart in React, is there a way to show a tooltip on an annotation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, apexcharts

I've a line series of type datetime. I need a way to add some points on this timeline indicating when the user must do an action. I need a way to display additional information on those points.

At first, I wanted to use annotations, but I need a way to show a tooltip when a user hover on an annotation.

I've also thought of using a second series for my points, but the 'shared' tooltip option doesn't seem to work and it only shows the tooltip of the line series if a point is over a point of the line series.

thank you